# Is there a word for a node in a connected graph that has the property that its removal creates a disconnected graph?

Tags: graph-theory

The simplest example is node 2 in the chain 1-2-3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name is *articulation point* or a *cut vertex*.

See this nice [graph theory glossary](http://www.utm.edu/departments/math/graph/glossary.html).

Answer (score 1):

Such a vertex is simply called a cut vertex.